# Received JSON cuts off the beginning

Tags: c#, arrays, json, unity-game-engine

I am receiving `JSON` arrays in my Unity project using C#. However, it sometimes misses the first part of the array during reading.

This is the code reading it:

```
while(sck.Connected){
    byte[] buffer = new byte[100000];
    int rec = sck.Receive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, 0);
    Array.Resize(ref buffer, rec);


    text = Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer);   
}
```

When receiving the following array, it somehow loses the first part.

```
[
    {
        "id": 27,
        "question": "What color is #FF0000 in Hexadecimal",
        "answers": [
            {
                "answer": "red",
                "correct": 1
            },
            {
                "answer": "blue",
                "correct": 0
            },
            {
                "answer": "yellow",
                "correct": 0
            },
            {
                "answer": "green",
                "correct": 0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 80,
        "question": "Which language is the native language in Uruguay? ",
        "answers": [
            {
                "answer": "Portuguese",
                "correct": 0
            },
            {
                "answer": "Uruguese",
                "correct": 0
            },
            {
                "answer": "English",
                "correct": 0
            },
            {
                "answer": "Spanish",
                "correct": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 109,
        "question": "What World War II operation was code named 'Barbarossa'?",
        "answers": [
            {
                "answer": "Invasion of Africa",
                "correct": 0
            },
            {
                "answer": "Invasion of The Soviet Union ",
                "correct": 1
            },
            {
                "answer": "Invasion of France",
                "correct": 0
            },
            {
                "answer": "Invasion of Denmark",
                "correct": 0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 118,
        "question": "The cassowary and Emu are both flightless birds of which country? ",
        "answers": [
            {
                "answer": "South Africa",
                "correct": 0
            },
            {
                "answer": "India",
                "correct": 0
            },
            {
                "answer": "Brazil",
                "correct": 0
            },
            {
                "answer": "Australia",
                "correct": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 13,
        "question": "10-12*4=?",
        "answers": [
            {
                "answer": "-38",
                "correct": 1
            },
            {
                "answer": "38",
                "correct": 0
            },
            {
                "answer": "8",
                "correct": 0
            },
            {
                "answer": "-8",
                "correct": 0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 96,
        "question": "What is not a type of knitted fabric?",
        "answers": [
            {
                "answer": "Terry",
                "correct": 0
            },
            {
                "answer": "Jersey",
                "correct": 0
            },
            {
                "answer": "Rib",
                "correct": 0
            },
            {
                "answer": "Sateen",
                "correct": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 33,
        "question": "Which movie involves worm holes, teenagers and a bunny rabbit?",
        "answers": [
            {
                "answer": "Lord of the Rings",
                "correct": 0
            },
            {
                "answer": "Clueless",
                "correct": 0
            },
            {
                "answer": "Donnie Darko",
                "correct": 1
            },
            {
                "answer": "Star Wars",
                "correct": 0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 99,
        "question": "Which musician did not die at the age of 27?",
        "answers": [
            {
                "answer": "Kurt Cobain",
                "correct": 0
            },
            {
                "answer": "Amy Winehouse",
                "correct": 0
            },
            {
                "answer": "Janis Joplin",
                "correct": 0
            },
            {
                "answer": "Freddie Mercury",
                "correct": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 54,
        "question": "What was the apex predator in the 1993 film \"Jurassic Park\"?",
        "answers": [
            {
                "answer": "Tyrannosaurus ",
                "correct": 1
            },
            {
                "answer": "Dilophosauridae",
                "correct": 0
            },
            {
                "answer": "Denver",
                "correct": 0
            },
            {
                "answer": "Velociraptor",
                "correct": 0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 49,
        "question": "Who is serving breakfast for Rory Mcllroy?",
        "answers": [
            {
                "answer": "Caroline Wocniacki",
                "correct": 1
            },
            {
                "answer": "Anna Kournikova",
                "correct": 0
            },
            {
                "answer": "Serena Williams",
                "correct": 0
            },
            {
                "answer": "Miss Piggy",
                "correct": 0
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The array gets cut off at `||`

```
{"answer":"Clueless","co||rrect":0},{"answer":"Donnie Darko","correct":1}
```

However, it processes this `array` just fine:

```
[
    {
        "id": 121,
        "question": "How many miles do the teams race in the Oxford and Cambridge boat race ? ",
        "answers": [
            {
                "answer": "4",
                "correct": 1
            },
            {
                "answer": "1",
                "correct": 0
            },
            {
                "answer": "2",
                "correct": 0
            },
            {
                "answer": "3",
                "correct": 0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 61,
        "question": "How many different Formula 1 teams has Kimi Raikkonen driven for up to 2014?",
        "answers": [
            {
                "answer": "2",
                "correct": 0
            },
            {
                "answer": "6",
                "correct": 0
            },
            {
                "answer": "4",
                "correct": 1
            },
            {
                "answer": "10",
                "correct": 0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 57,
        "question": "Which muppet is Swedish?",
        "answers": [
            {
                "answer": "Miss Piggy",
                "correct": 0
            },
            {
                "answer": "Chef",
                "correct": 1
            },
            {
                "answer": "Yodel",
                "correct": 0
            },
            {
                "answer": "Gonzo",
                "correct": 0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 49,
        "question": "Who is serving breakfast for Rory Mcllroy?",
        "answers": [
            {
                "answer": "Caroline Wocniacki",
                "correct": 1
            },
            {
                "answer": "Anna Kournikova",
                "correct": 0
            },
            {
                "answer": "Serena Williams",
                "correct": 0
            },
            {
                "answer": "Miss Piggy",
                "correct": 0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 116,
        "question": "What is the highest active volcano in Europe ? ",
        "answers": [
            {
                "answer": "Vesuvius",
                "correct": 0
            },
            {
                "answer": "Eyjafjallajökull",
                "correct": 0
            },
            {
                "answer": "The sky mountain",
                "correct": 0
            },
            {
                "answer": "Etna",
                "correct": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 56,
        "question": " In 2013 How many people lived china",
        "answers": [
            {
                "answer": "0,8 billions",
                "correct": 0
            },
            {
                "answer": "0,6 billions",
                "correct": 0
            },
            {
                "answer": "2,0 billions",
                "correct": 0
            },
            {
                "answer": "1,3 billions",
                "correct": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 47,
        "question": "You have 3 red cars, 42 yellow cars and 21 green cars. How many cars are left if you half all the yellow cars and double the green cars.",
        "answers": [
            {
                "answer": "42",
                "correct": 0
            },
            {
                "answer": "66",
                "correct": 1
            },
            {
                "answer": "3",
                "correct": 0
            },
            {
                "answer": "63",
                "correct": 0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 28,
        "question": "If you mix blue and red you will get",
        "answers": [
            {
                "answer": "Green",
                "correct": 0
            },
            {
                "answer": "Orange",
                "correct": 0
            },
            {
                "answer": "Purple",
                "correct": 1
            },
            {
                "answer": "Pink",
                "correct": 0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 141,
        "question": "Which spirit is used in a Bloody Mary?",
        "answers": [
            {
                "answer": "Vodka",
                "correct": 1
            },
            {
                "answer": "Rum",
                "correct": 0
            },
            {
                "answer": "Gin",
                "correct": 0
            },
            {
                "answer": "Whisky",
                "correct": 0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 45,
        "question": "Which character in the TV series \"Game of Thrones\" is the centre of lust for many males around the world?",
        "answers": [
            {
                "answer": "Queen Freelus",
                "correct": 0
            },
            {
                "answer": "Daenerys Targaryen",
                "correct": 1
            },
            {
                "answer": "Princess Liea",
                "correct": 0
            },
            {
                "answer": "Madam Butterfly",
                "correct": 0
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The JSON itself was valid. So it must be the code or the connection.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your buffer isn't large enough.

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[100000];
```

I would look into a few different options depending on your needs for the code

1. Increase the size of the buffer
2. Use a [memory stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream(v=vs.110).aspx)
3. [Asynchronous Server Socket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te(v=vs.110).aspx)